# Image transform with CSS

Tags: css

I would like to hover over an image to enlarge it say 3 times then when i click on the enlarged image it goes back to the original size. Can this be done purely with CSS ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't track click events.

You can use `:hover` to scale it up and `:active` to scale it down but as soon as you move your cursor the image will again get scaled up because of `:hover` effect.

```
img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

img:active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

**But this isn't a good practice.**

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't support clicks. You can zoom on hover with

```
img:hover {transform: scale(300%);}
```

but it will shrink as soon as the user moves away

Comment: Think you missed the `:hover`!

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can, but it's not pretty and I wouldn't recommend doing it in pure CSS:

```css
.thing {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.thing label, .thing img {
  transform: scale(0.33);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform .4s;
}
.thing label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.thing input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.thing input:checked ~ img,
.thing input:checked ~ label {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb">
    <label for="cb"></label>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```